# Check for structure key in array element using cfscript

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to loop over an array called meta.

I am having issues with checking if an element exists. In this array sometimes the length is present and sometimes it is not. I am trying to get something like this to work:

```
for (i=1;i LTE ArrayLen(meta);i=i+1) {

    if (meta[i].length==undefined) {

       maxLen = '1';
    }
    else    
    {

       maxLen = meta[i].length;

    }

}
```

I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want a structkeyexists.

```
if (structkeyexists(meta[i],"length") ....
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. I was playing with structkeyexists but I did not have the syntax correct. Thanks

Comment: For arrays, use this: `ArrayIsDefined(array, elementIndex)`